# Adding more Data to a Commerce Feed Upload

Tags: commerce, feeds, importing-exporting

Currently I'm working on a Commerce Kickstart 2 storefront, to remake our company website in Drupal, a store front for selling Television Repair parts. I have a little HTML/CSS experience under my belt, but no real experience with Drupal outside of a couple tutorials. While I have figured out how to upload listings from the old website through tutorial videos and the Commerce Feed module, I could use a resource on how to add more information a CSV upload, more than a SKU, Name, Price, Image and a Description. Is it possible to add data to the CSV regarding Manufacturers, Part Number, intended TV Model, Condition of the part, and other useful information that users could sort and search for products with, or would any sorting and tagging have to be done after the objects are uploaded into the system? If there is a common method, where would be a good resource to start with to figure out what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

A Commerce feed fundamentally isn't any different to a regular feed so if you need additional data attached to your product you should be able to create the additional fields you need on your product type and in Feeds map the data from your CSV to the Product Type fields in Commerce.

With regards to sorting, wouldn't you be doing that in Views when you're actually displaying the imported products?